# margin:auto not working in FTL file

Tags: java, css, freemarker

I am preparing html body by using FTL template (in Java). I have written css as follows:

```
width: 620px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

also tried `margin: auto;`

FTL not considering `auto` keyword from css.

Could you please help anyone on this.

Comment: width: 620px;
margin-left: auto:
margin-right: auto;

Comment: Can you post more of the ftl file?

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't interpret CSS, the browser does. So this question is not related to FTL. It's a CSS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width: 620px
margin-left: auto
margin-right: auto
```

You have to close the code at the end.

```
width: 620px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

and maybe you can use `margin:100%;` to solve it

Comment: Yes ended with quotes. Due to some format issue I am not able to keep ; at the end.